# El capitan OS X Server 5.1 upgrade breaks virtualhosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, osx-elcapitan, osx-server

It's been 2 years I am running OS X server, had more or less troubles with it. Yesterday, I updated to server 5.1 and web server completely broke. All settings looks there in Web section panel of server app.

[image]

However when looking for the site, Safari could not find it. I dig several hours on this issue and find out that virtual_host_global.conf contains only this :

```
# This file is auto-generated by the Server application's
# configuration mechanism whenever settings are saved.
# The Listen directives are generated
# based on the VirtualHost directive inside
# each site configuration file found in this directory.

Listen  127.0.0.1:34543
Listen  127.0.0.1:34580
```

After updating it manually to this

```
# This file is auto-generated by the web configuration
# mechanism whenever settings are saved.
# The Listen and NameVirtualHost directives are generated
# based on the VirtualHost directive inside
# each site configuration file found in this directory.
#
Listen  *:443
Listen  *:80
```

And restarting server everything went back to normal. However if I change settings from server app the app rewrite this file and breaks everything.

I don't understand why it breaks from a simple update. Does anyone knows how to make my modification permanent? Which configuration file or items in Server app do I need to change to have it working everytime I change something from server UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem!

First and foremost I found documentation here

> /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/ReadMe.txt

In this document, I found a command to reset server service to factory settings (BE CAREFUL TO SAVE YOUR DATA BEFORE, /Library/Server/Web/ folder)

> sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serveradmin
>   command web:command=restoreFactorySettings

After this reset, website service just worked nicely. I don't really know what went wrong during server update. But I suspect something as I notice a new redirect parameter on my default site that wasn't present before the factory setting reset

[image: Default site has now 1 redirect]

Here is detail of redirect panel :

[image: Detail of redirect]

Therefor, if you have such a big issue regarding Web service part of new OS X server app. Don't hesitate to reset it to factory setting as upgrade can break it.